# Denavit-Hartenberg Humanoid robot

Tags: forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

In humanoid robot, Which way we determine DH Parameter:

1. DH parameter for each leg separability.
2. Or, DH-Parameter for two leg together.

and if I can calculate from any way, what about trunk how can insert it in DH calculation?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no idea about where to start the best is to google Nao + DarwinOP + HUBO2 + DH and you will have lot of pdf articles and reports coming out that you may read. For each humanoid robot you will have a description of kinematic chains and DH modeling.

Answer (score 0):

When establishing a set of kinematic frames for a humanoid robot, it's common to use a frame on the torso as the base frame and then branch out to the limbs from there. So there is a tree of kinematic frames. The base frame is a floating frame.

DH parameterization of the kinematics can be useful for drawings and showing or communicating the relative positioning of joints, but you will probably find that it's easier to work with full SE3 transforms between frames instead of trying to use DH parameters.